# Apache Kafka ksqlDB forward stream to existing topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm still playing with ksqlDB to understand what it can and what it cannot do, so I jut might be missing something obvious.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```sql
-- Define input stream for raw data
CREATE STREAM user_input (
  a VARCHAR,
  b VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'user_input',
  PARTITIONS = 1,
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);

-- Then define table that would hold input data, keyed
CREATE TABLE user_input_keyed (
  key VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  a VARCHAR,
  B VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'user_input_keyed',
  PARTITIONS = 1,
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);

-- And then define substream that would append key to input stream
CREATE STREAM user_input_keyer WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'user_input_keyed', -- this is the same topic as for TABLE user_input_keyed 
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
) AS SELECT UUID() key, a, b
FROM user_input
EMIT CHANGES;

-- This construction would allow me to eliminate certain data entries by newly 
-- generated key by sending tombstone message like this:
INSERT INTO user_input_keyed (key) VALUES (${some UUID});

-- Event more - by using this technique I could actually invoke ksqlDB level
-- tombstones as well.
-- We can imagine this scheme being extended to not only receive new data, but 
-- some updates as well.
-- So I could have it like this

CREATE STREAM user_input_update (
  key VARCHAR KEY,
  a VARCHAR,
  b VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'user_input_update',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);
CREATE STREAM user_input_removed WITH ( 
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'user_input_keyer',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
) AS SELECT key 
FROM user_input_update
WHERE a IS NULL
EMIT CHANGES;
```

So the question is - is this actually supported?

I've seen this approach in some code I've found online but I haven't seen this been documented anywhere.

Also, this code is actually working but is messing up some fields/values at times, so I'd like to see if I'm not banging at a closed door and there's not really that much ksqlDB been at v 0.13 can do.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a bit clearer about *what* you're trying to do? I appreciate the example code but I'm still not sure what it is you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: I want to turn stream of incoming data into a keyed table, which then can be cleared of certain entries by key generated in a process.